# Memory leak when linking against opencv

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, valgrind

I'm linking a library against opencv libraries. I noticed that when I run the unit test executable (using GTest) for that library, that valgrind reports a memory leak/conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value, even when the test doesn't do anything at all (just empty test method).

I traced that issue back to a single line in my `CMakeLists.txt` - when I remove the linkage against opencv, the memory leak goes away. This is the releavant snippet:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(libImageSources src/SourceImageFile.cpp)

add_library(image SHARED ${libImageSources})

# removing this line fixes the leak:
target_link_libraries(image ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Otherwise when runnig an empty unit test, I get an error like this:

```
==18681== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18681== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18681== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18681== Command: ./image_test /Users/max/Documents/playground/cpp/image-server/tests
==18681==
==18681== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==18681==    at 0x7FFF5FC24A27: bcmp (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC11904: ImageLoaderMachO::validateFirstPages(linkedit_data_command const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, long long, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC16B7A: ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, linkedit_data_command const*, encryption_info_command const*, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC10A6E: ImageLoaderMachO::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC038C2: dyld::loadPhase6(int, stat const&, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC08468: dyld::loadPhase5(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC08188: dyld::loadPhase4(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC07EED: dyld::loadPhase3(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC07642: dyld::loadPhase1(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC0347A: dyld::loadPhase0(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC0315E: dyld::load(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC08705: dyld::libraryLocator(char const*, bool, char const*, ImageLoader::RPathChain const*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==
==18681== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==18681==    at 0x7FFF5FC24A3F: bcmp (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC11904: ImageLoaderMachO::validateFirstPages(linkedit_data_command const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, long long, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC16B7A: ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, linkedit_data_command const*, encryption_info_command const*, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC10A6E: ImageLoaderMachO::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC038C2: dyld::loadPhase6(int, stat const&, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC08468: dyld::loadPhase5(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC08188: dyld::loadPhase4(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC07EED: dyld::loadPhase3(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC07642: dyld::loadPhase1(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC0347A: dyld::loadPhase0(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC0315E: dyld::load(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC08705: dyld::libraryLocator(char const*, bool, char const*, ImageLoader::RPathChain const*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==
==18681== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==18681==    at 0x7FFF5FC24A44: bcmp (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC11904: ImageLoaderMachO::validateFirstPages(linkedit_data_command const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, long long, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC16B7A: ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, linkedit_data_command const*, encryption_info_command const*, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC10A6E: ImageLoaderMachO::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC038C2: dyld::loadPhase6(int, stat const&, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC08468: dyld::loadPhase5(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC08188: dyld::loadPhase4(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC07EED: dyld::loadPhase3(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC07642: dyld::loadPhase1(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC0347A: dyld::loadPhase0(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC0315E: dyld::load(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC08705: dyld::libraryLocator(char const*, bool, char const*, ImageLoader::RPathChain const*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==
==18681== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==18681==    at 0x7FFF5FC11907: ImageLoaderMachO::validateFirstPages(linkedit_data_command const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, long long, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC16B7A: ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, linkedit_data_command const*, encryption_info_command const*, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC10A6E: ImageLoaderMachO::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC038C2: dyld::loadPhase6(int, stat const&, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC08468: dyld::loadPhase5(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC08188: dyld::loadPhase4(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC07EED: dyld::loadPhase3(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC07642: dyld::loadPhase1(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC0347A: dyld::loadPhase0(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC0315E: dyld::load(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC08705: dyld::libraryLocator(char const*, bool, char const*, ImageLoader::RPathChain const*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==    by 0x7FFF5FC0E85D: ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==18681==
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from ImageProcessingConfigurationService
[ RUN      ] ImageProcessingConfigurationService.evaluateConfigurationFile
[       OK ] ImageProcessingConfigurationService.evaluateConfigurationFile (13 ms)
[----------] 1 test from ImageProcessingConfigurationService (28 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (114 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
==18681==
==18681== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18681==     in use at exit: 1,346,030 bytes in 1,453 blocks
==18681==   total heap usage: 2,926 allocs, 1,473 frees, 3,045,052 bytes allocated
==18681==
==18681== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18681==    definitely lost: 10,580 bytes in 137 blocks
==18681==    indirectly lost: 10,032 bytes in 152 blocks
==18681==      possibly lost: 9,568 bytes in 183 blocks
==18681==    still reachable: 43,598 bytes in 520 blocks
==18681==         suppressed: 1,272,252 bytes in 461 blocks
==18681== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==18681==
==18681== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18681== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==18681== ERROR SUMMARY: 36 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Compiler is clang++ Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31), OS X El Capitan (10.11.1).

Anyone else has had an issue like that? It seems stuff works nontheless, but the error creates noise that I'd rather ignore, I'm not sure if I can fix the root cause.

Comment: `... that valgrind reports a memory leak/invalid free` - In the error log I see only memory leak plus `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value` in dynamic loader. No "invalid free" or so.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that is true, I meant the `jump on unitialized value` message, sorry. I think this is most likely a false positive by valgrind, I used the OS X profiler to check for memory leaks and it seemed fine.

Comment: @usr1234567 I think it's unrelated to CMake as I debugged it, but thank you for your pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems like a false positive reported by valgrind which I can ignore as it's not caused by code.

I tried (at the time of writing) the latest [valgrind suppressions file for macOS](https://github.com/svn2github/valgrind/blob/master/darwin14.supp) which didn't work for me, the issue was still reported.

I let [valgrind dump the suppressions](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto) needed to ignore this error, using a command like:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --error-limit=no --gen-suppressions=all --log-file=l.log ./image_test
```

And then used [a tool to parse the log output](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Parse_valgrind_suppressions.sh) (the awk script didn't work for me as it contained a syntax error, I used the perl version) into a suppressions file:

```
cat l.log | ./parse_valgrind_suppressions.pl > s.supp
```

Now running the test with the generated suppresions file ignores the memory leak:

```
valgrind --suppressions=./s.supp ./image_test
```